# Change default editor from vi to vim or nvim on FreeBSD

Tags: environment-variables, editor, freebsd

How can I change the default editor in FreeBSD (using bash) from vi to vim (or in my case nvim).

Here's what I've tried (for nvim):

in `/etc/profile` (I'd like to nvim to be editor for all users)

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/nvim"
```

in `~/.bash_profile`

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/nvim"
```

in `~/.bashrc`

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/nvim"
```

in `~/.profile`

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/nvim"
```

I'm running out of options here. There seem to be a lot of opinions but there's nothing helpful in the FreeBSD documentation.

Comment: BSD's are more likely to use csh as a default interactive shell than bash (ymmv).

Comment: Indeed. FreeBSD uses tcsh by default. What does `echo $SHELL` give you? You can change the shell with `chsh` (bash isn't installed by default, install `editors/bash` to get it). In addition, many programs don't use `$EDITOR`, so you should describe what *exactly* isn't working.

Comment: One of the first utilities I install on every FreeBSD of mine is bash. So, yes, I mean bash. I apologize for not having been sufficiently specific.

Comment: Alight, just checking :-) You'll still need to describe what *exactly* isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  Could you do "echo $EDITOR" in the shell and verify if it's being set properly?

Also, I seem to remember the VISUAL takes precedence over EDITOR, so check whether that's set.

Answer (score 1):

To globally change the editor you could edit the `/etc/login.conf` file and have something like this:

```
default:\
        :passwd_format=sha512:\
        :copyright=/etc/COPYRIGHT:\
        :welcome=/etc/motd:\
        :setenv=MAIL=/var/mail/$,BLOCKSIZE=K,EDITOR=vim:\
        ...
```

Notice the `setenv` line:

```
:setenv=MAIL=/var/mail/$,BLOCKSIZE=K,EDITOR=vim:\
```

After editing the file you need to run:

```
# cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf
```

This will basically set the `EDITOR` environment var to your preferred editor, the one can be overwritten by using custom `.(cshrc|zshrc|profile)`